# Why does setting the modifiedDate for a Google Drive file cause a crash in the iOS Drive api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Executing the following to upload a local file to a Google Drive causes a crash.

```
GTLDriveFile *gFile = [GTLDriveFile object];
gFile.title = "MyFileName.txt";

// Other file setup

NSDate *myLocalDate = [self fileDate:myPath];
gFile.modifiedDate  = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:myLocalDate timeZone:gmtZone];

// Other GTLQueryDrive and GTLUploadParameters calls

query.setModifiedDate = YES;
[service executeQuery:query completionHandler: (etc)
```

The fileDate:path method returns the fileModificationDate attribute of the local file being uploaded.  The crash message is:

Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Invalid value for: Invalid format: "2014-09-14T13:21:58+00:00" is malformed

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered how to properly set the modifiedDate for a Google Drive file as posted in stackoverflow question 14193307.  I then ran into the problem shown above and discovered that the crash is probably a bug in the Google Drive SDK.  My successful work around is to add another line to my fileDate:path method as follows:

```
- (NSDate *)fileDate:(NSString *)path {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fMgr attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    long long t = [attributes.fileModificationDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:t+.1];
}
```

When the Google Drive SDK converts its internal date into a JSON string it seems to drop the .xxx millisecond portion if xxx=0.  So the inelegant code above forces .xxx to be .100 so that the modifiedDate string becomes e.g. {2014-09-20T05:58:37.100+00:00} which is valid.